# CSV to SQLite in R (dbWriteTable): passing factors

Tags: r, csv, sqldf

I'm using this workflow to process a large csv file in R:

```
library(sqldf)

csv <- "db.csv"
sqlite_file <- "db.sqlite"
table_name <- "table"

db <- src_sqlite(sqlite_file, create = TRUE)
con <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = sqlite_file)
dbWriteTable(con, name=table_name, value=csv, 
             row.names=FALSE, header=TRUE, sep = ",", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Then I create my queries, fetch the data and so on and so forth. Data will look like this:

```
ID     Class     V1   V2   V3 ...
1      1.1       100  234  423
2      5         221  345  563
3      2.2.2     240  356  250
4      3.1       267  569  867
5      6         125  469  596
```

The column `Class`, in the original .csv file, is a factor with the following 10 levels:

```
"1.1"   "1.2"   "2.1"   "2.2.1" "2.2.2" "3.1"   "3.2"   "4"     "5"     "6"
```

However, once I pass the csv file to sqlite and fetch it back into R, the factor loses two of its levels:

```
"1.1" "1.2" "2.1" "2.2" "3.1" "3.2" "4"   "5"   "6"
```

I supposed that, while passing the csv to sqlite, the factor was read as a number and I was right. Since in this way I misclassify some data, do you know how could I avoid this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since the large csv was only a product of previous processing, I solved by simply importing another csv which contained only the IDs and the classes.

After fetching data by the SQL statement, I cast the dataframe by data.table and solve with an update join in the following way:

```
tags <- fread("ID_class.csv")

df <- dbFetch(query)
df <- data.table(df)
df$Class <- as.character(df$Class)
df <- df[tags, on=.(ID), Class := i.Class]
df$Class <- factor(df$Class)
```

It's not the most elegant way nor the most efficient (you need a previous csv with the right classes), but it worked for me for this issue. Any other advice or suggestion will be appreciated.